# Backround colour of search bar changes after choosing suggestions

Tags: css, web, searchbar

I want to remove the white color totally.

Before selecting the suggestions

[image]

After choosing one of the suggestions

[image]

```
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid #1de9b6;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 0.375rem 1.25rem;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.2s;
  transition: border-color 0.2s;
  color: white;
}
```

```
input[type="search"]:focus {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #00a2ff;
  /* border-color: #f9d342; */
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I am using chrome by the way.

Comment: can you create an example?

Comment: @godfather , Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: create a snippet or add more code so we can reproduce it and test it

Comment: can you add the html or is there somewhere  we can test it?

Comment: @godfather https://codepen.io/jake1230/pen/jOWqywv

Comment: lets wait becasue its working fine for me

Comment: are you using javascript ? if yes add it to codepen

Comment: @godfather Nope